# how to display the username of the comment in the post with relation table

Tags: laravel

[my relational database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpT9M.png)

```
{{ \App\User::where('id', $comment->user_id)->value('name') }}
```

if I use the code above

name user show in all post

my model

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Komen extends Model
{
    protected $table='komentar_post';


}
```

my controller

```
public function index()
{
    $post=Post::all();
    $comment=Komen::all();
    $user=User::all();

    // dd($id);
    return view('home',compact('post','comment','user'));
}
```

my view

```
@foreach($comments as $cm)
                {{ \App\User::where('id', $cm->user_id)->value('name') }}
                @endforeach
```

what the corect query i must use

Comment: You need to provide us more code when questioning. Something like your Controller code and your model (we need to know what's your current relationship setup).

Comment: A few issues here. 1st, don't execute queries in your `view`; that's what controllers are for. 2nd, if you have a loop, don't execute queries in a loop, as that causes an `n+1` issue and might crash your page due to too long loading. 3rd, use relationships. Your models should each relate to each other, then you can use `Post::with(["comments", "comments.user"])->get();` to load the model and relationship(s), completely avoiding the querying issues 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create relationship in your `Komen` model. It's something like this:

```php
class Komen extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Then, you can [Eager Load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) that relationship when fetching the `Komen`.

**PostsController.php**

```php
public function show(Post $post)
{
    $comments = $post->comments()->with('user')->paginate();

    return view('posts.show', compact('comments'));
}
```

Then, you can access `user` data when displaying each comments:

**posts/show.blade.php**

```php
@foreach($comments as $comment)
    {{ $comment->user->name }}
@endforeach


{!! $comments->links() !!}
```

**Update**

Ok, if you need to displaying comments when you're displaying all posts, first you need to setup the `relationship`!

**Post.php**

```php
class Post extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Komen::class, 'post_id');
    }
}
```

**Komen.php**

```php
class Komen extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

**PostsController.php**

```php
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::with('comments.user')->paginate();

    return view('home', compact('posts'));
}
```

**home.blade.php**

```php
@foreach($posts as $post)
    @foreach($post->comments as $comment)
        {{ $comment->user->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach

{!! $posts->links() !!}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202073/discussion-on-answer-by-nmfzone-how-to-display-the-username-of-the-comment-in-th).